# Update MySQL Row using ADO.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql

I am trying to update a row in MySQL database from within ASP.NET using ASP.NET.

```
    MySqlConnection cnx = new MySqlConnection(con);
    MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof(Int32) );
    dt.Columns.Add("config", typeof(string) );
    dt.TableName = "sharding_conf";
    DataRow dr =  dt.NewRow();
    dr["id"] = 1;
    dr["config"] = json;
    int ok = adapter.Update(dt);

    lblTest.Text = ok.ToString();

    cnx.Dispose();
    adapter.Dispose();
```

However the row is not getting updated, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Please you done like that ex: 

SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection("Your Connection String");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

cmd.CommandText = "insert into tablename(colname1,columnname2) values(val1,val2)";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;

sqlConnection1.Open();

cmd.ExecuteNonQuey();

sqlConnection1.Close();
```

Comment: the question is about update command query not about insert command. They are totally different scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing mySqlconnection instance as argument in [`MysqlDataAdapter`](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/docs/Parameters.html)

if no then try the alternate way using [`mySqlCommand`](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/docs/Parameters.html) in which pass your `Update` query. I know this much only.

and instead of disposing your objects manually use [`Using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) Statement.

Refer this **[link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/71346/Connecting-to-MySQL-Database-using-C-and-NET)** for more understanding.